# Django: can't login after editing user details

Tags: django

I'm trying to find a solution for 2 days now... can't figure out why login does not work for me once I have changed any user details.

Normal flow works fine for me: user registers, logs in and out without a problem. But I thought it would be good to have profile change option where a user can change username, password or email. I did implement this, but after a user changes anything (even email), the login form does not admit him.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from .forms import ContactForm, CreateUserForm, EditUserForm
    
class ProfileView(UpdateView):
        template_name = 'boat_app/edit_profile.html'
        form_class = UserChangeForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('anchored')
    
        def get_object(self):
            return self.request.user


class LoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'boat_app/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('category_home')

    def post(self, request):
        print(request)
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST.get('username'), password=request.POST.get('password'))

        if user is not None:
            print('user not none')
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('anchored'))
        else:
            print('user none')
            messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
```

And forms.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

    class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username', 'email')
```

After changing a user I see this change in admin interface, so it does work. But I can't see a reason why the system does not see this relation. Any way to debug what exactly is going on there?

**UPDATE**

I've tried changing the user via admin backend - all works fine. I've also tried using {{ form.as_p }} instead of my custom template for ProfileView - and this also worked! So apparently there is something fishy going on with my html template which ruins the update view and does nont allow to collect data for future login.

Here is my 'boat_app/edit_profile.html'

```
{% block body_block %}

<div class="row align-items-center vh-100">
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-md-block">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container p-3 text-center bg-light">

      <div class="my-3">
        <h1>Change your details</h1>
        <p>Did something change?</p>
      </div>


      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="form-group row px-3">
          <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">{{form.username.label}}</label>
          {% render_field form.username class="form-control" %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row px-3">
          {{ form.email.errors }}
          <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">{{form.email.label}}</label>
          {% render_field form.email class="form-control" %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row px-3">
          {{ form.password.errors }}
          <label for="{{ form.date_joined.id_for_label }}">{{form.date_joined.label}}</label>
          {% render_field form.date_joined class="form-control" %}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row text-left px-3">
          <p>If you need to change password, click <a href="{% url 'password' %}">here</a>.</p>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

      </form>


    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-md-block">
  </div>
</div>



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you use the `UserChangeForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms` in your view? Also you have some form `EditUserForm` but I don't see you using it?

Comment: I have added some imports to the post above.
UserChangeForm is only used in that class.

EditUserForm - you right, it's not used now. I've lost track of changes trying to make it work. Initially I used it in ProfileView class, but later replaced it by standard UserChangeForm

Comment: Does it return an error?

Comment: No, it does not. Well, if I try to login with updated details, it just refuses me access. The form says "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." But the code does not break

Comment: @DmitryKhavanskiy I believe you used some form earlier in which you attempted to change password and you had made this form on your own? This might have caused the problem of your users password to be set incorrectly (unhashed). And now when you try to login it doesn't work because the unhashed password is tested with the hashed one.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat My only attempt of working with passwords was this view, but I guess this is how it should be tackled. And in any case this should not present an issue if I created another test user, follow the same change of details and login does not work again.

class EditPasswordView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'boat_app/password.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('anchored')

Comment: @DmitryKhavanskiy You might not have tried changing the password but did you have the field in the form?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat initially I had a standard user change form which included password field (or rather a link to a proper page). That's it, nothing else.

I guess there is not much that can be done in such a mess as I have now... Do you have any advice on where to find a full proper procedure of organizing a login system? I'd better start fresh, rather than breaking my head any longer... I have a very simple case actually: standard user model, extended by just one field (device from cookies). Want people to be able to login, logout, change details

Comment: I've added some more information to the original post. The issue seems to be exactly with html template and how data is collected in the first place (when updating the user)